# Increasing value for key which is existing in dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'm trying to create concordance.
I have dictionary, where key -  is word and value - is frequency of this word
If word exist in dictionary  I need to increase value for this word.
I'm using ContainsKey to check if word exists, bot don't understand how to increase value

```
    string[] words = SplitWords(lines);

    foreach (var  word in words)
    {
            int i = 0;
            if (!concordanceDictionary.ContainsKey(word))
            {
                concordanceDictionary.Add(word, i);
            }
            else
            {

            }
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> pair in concordanceDictionary)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}",pair.Key, pair.Value);
           }
        }
```

Comment: Hmm, better make that concordanceDictionary.Add(word, 1);

Comment: If the key exists increase the value with `concordanceDictionary[word]++`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the [*indexer*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9tee9ht2(v=vs.110).aspx) property:

```
if (!concordanceDictionary.ContainsKey(word))
{
    concordanceDictionary.Add(word, 1);
}
else
{
    concordanceDictionary[word]++;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

just do

```
else
{
    concordanceDictionary[word]++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the test for ContainsKeys fails and after adding the key, just increment the value.
There is no need of the else block

```
string[] words = SplitWords(lines);
foreach (var  word in words)
{
    if (!concordanceDictionary.ContainsKey(word))
       concordanceDictionary.Add(word, 0);
    concordanceDictionary[word]++;
}
```